# Why does implicit intents sometimes launch incorrect activity/intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, react-native, intentfilter

I'm adding the possibility to recieve files into my react-native app. For example open a pdf file from an email or send an image from the gallery. But sometimes it's not working and when it's not working it seems the incorrect activity was selected from the implicit intent created by those apps.

I have added some logging to see what is happening.

Not working example from logcat, MainActivity intent used:

```
01-21 17:20:34.232 11518 11577 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "PowerupShareEx" with appParams: {"rootTag":41}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
01-21 17:20:34.242 11518 11578 D ReactNativeJS activity: com.frenberg.powerup.MainActivity@159c271
01-21 17:20:34.242 11518 11578 D ReactNativeJS intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.frenberg.powerup.alfa/com.frenberg.powerup.MainActivity bnds=[726,316][1062,732] (has extras) }
01-21 17:20:34.243 11518 11578 D ReactNativeJS activity: com.frenberg.powerup.MainActivity@159c271
01-21 17:20:34.243 11518 11578 D ReactNativeJS intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.frenberg.powerup.alfa/com.frenberg.powerup.MainActivity bnds=[726,316][1062,732] (has extras) }
```

Working example from logcat, ShareActivity intent used which contains correct data:

```
01-21 17:20:58.248 11518 11577 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "PowerupShareEx" with appParams: {"rootTag":51}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
01-21 17:20:58.261 11518 11578 D ReactNativeJS activity: com.frenberg.share.ShareActivity@86e955f
01-21 17:20:58.263 11518 11578 D ReactNativeJS intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.google.android.gm.sapi/appuser01@frenberg.com/message_attachment_external/#thread-f:1623272236728858938/#msg-f:1623272236728858938/0.1?account_type=com.google&mimeType=application/pdf&rendition=1 typ=application/pdf flg=0x13080001 cmp=com.frenberg.powerup.alfa/com.frenberg.share.ShareActivity }
01-21 17:20:58.288 11518 11578 D ReactNativeJS activity: com.frenberg.share.ShareActivity@86e955f
01-21 17:20:58.288 11518 11578 D ReactNativeJS intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.google.android.gm.sapi/appuser01@frenberg.com/message_attachment_external/#thread-f:1623272236728858938/#msg-f:1623272236728858938/0.1?account_type=com.google&mimeType=application/pdf&rendition=1 typ=application/pdf flg=0x13080001 cmp=com.frenberg.powerup.alfa/com.frenberg.share.ShareActivity }
```

I'm new to android development, but I'm thinking this must have something to do with my AndroidManifest.xml-file. If you need something else, just ask.

```
<application
    tools:replace="android:label"
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:label="${appName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="${appName}"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="se.fortnox.powerup.action.OPEN_APP" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:label="${appName}">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "powerup://documentcollection” -->
            <data android:scheme="powerup"
                android:host="documentcollection" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    .........

    <!--  for sharing photos and pdfs -->
    <activity
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:name="se.fortnox.share.ShareActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="${appName}"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Share.Transparent" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpg" android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/tif" android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/tiff" android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

So i'm expecting the ShareActivity to always "get selected" but as you can tell from the logcat output above, in the "not working output" sometimes the MainActivity is launched instead.

Comment: On which android API you are testing?

Comment: @Prags I have tested this on two different samsung phones but both are on API 25

Comment: No, sorry that was the samsung knox api level. The android api is 26 on this galaxy S7.

Comment: It is working on any other device and on other api level?

Comment: I have an LG nexus 5 with api 27 that shows the same behaviour.